# In Vertx - how to make a callback?

Tags: java, vert.x, oauth-2.0

I have a problem with Vertx oauth2.

I followed this tutorial http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_oauth2authhandler_handler:

```
OAuth2Auth authProvider = OAuth2Auth.create(vertx, OAuth2FlowType.AUTH_CODE, new OAuth2ClientOptions()
    .setClientID("CLIENT_ID")
    .setClientSecret("CLIENT_SECRET")
    .setSite("https://github.com/login")
    .setTokenPath("/oauth/access_token")
    .setAuthorizationPath("/oauth/authorize"));

// create a oauth2 handler on our domain: "http://localhost:8080"
OAuth2AuthHandler oauth2 = OAuth2AuthHandler.create(authProvider, "http://localhost:8080");

// setup the callback handler for receiving the GitHub callback
oauth2.setupCallback(router.get("/callback"));

// protect everything under /protected
router.route("/protected/*").handler(oauth2);
// mount some handler under the protected zone
router.route("/protected/somepage").handler(rc -> {
  rc.response().end("Welcome to the protected resource!");
});

// welcome page
router.get("/").handler(ctx -> {
  ctx.response().putHeader("content-type", "text/html").end("Hello<br><a href=\"/protected/somepage\">Protected by Github</a>");
});
```

The ideas is to have in the protected folder all the webpages that requires auth.
When I want to access to protected webpage I get redirected to the microsoft login site and after the login I get redirected to my callback.

What I don´t understand is how to handle the callback now?
I get something like this as response:

```
https://localhost:8080/callback?code=AAABAAA...km1IgAA&session_state=....
```

How I understood (https://blog.mastykarz.nl/building-applications-office-365-apis-any-platform/) I need to extract somehow the code and the session-state and send back with a post to:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token
```

in order to get the token.

But I did not understand how this can be done with Vertx.
Any help? How to extract the code and session and send back to Microsoft?

I found some tutorials here: https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-auth/blob/master/vertx-auth-oauth2/src/main/java/examples/AuthOAuth2Examples.java but did not help me.

I am doing this with Azure authentication (in tutorial is written Github but i changed all this to Microsoft).

Answer (score 0):

Are you behind a proxy? The callback handler sends a request to the provider from the application and not from a browser. For me this froze the whole application. You can set the proxy with OAuth2ClientOptions given to the OAuth2Auth.create

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [official vert.x-web document](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_oauth2authhandler_handler), the handling of the auth flow (including access token request to microsoft) is handled by OAuth2AuthHandler:

> The OAuth2AuthHandler will setup a proper callback OAuth2 handler so the user does not need to deal with validation of the authority server response.

This being said, there is no need for application to manually handle it. Instead of using example from vertx-auth, try [this one](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/blob/master/web-examples/src/main/java/io/vertx/example/web/oauth2/Server.java) instead which actually uses OAuth2AuthHandler.